# Azure Functions memory / consumption unit usage

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to view memory usage / how many consumption units you are presently/historically using for Azure Functions?

I'm currently using the consumption plan for a function which handles messages from a service bus queue. Each message takes around 5 seconds to process and there are usually several hundred messages / second to be handled.

My fear is simply that at some point I will starting seeing outofmemoryexceptions with no forewarning, though it would also be helpful for me to get an idea of costing before being billed.

I've looked through the portal and all I've found is the success count and pulse (which never seems to report any data for my function. Though the graphs are drawn - they are always empty.)

There is also this blog post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/15/making-azure-functions-more-serverless/

..which essentially says that you do not need to specify your memory cap anymore and providing your usage is within 1.5GB & your processing is under the 5 minute timeout then life is good. Knowing how much room I have would be reassuring though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Monitor -> Metrics` view in the Azure Portal:

[image]

For more information on this topic see [this functions cost/billing FAQ](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think it's worth noting that to add memory working set to the graph you will have to disable the default selected options of execution units / execution count. I have around 350 million under execution units and 600 under execution count - what do these values translate to exactly?

Comment: Azure Functions consumption billing has two elements - GBsec and execution count. Function Execution Units correlates to GBsec but the issue is that its currently measured in MBmilliseconds. So what this means is that you need to divide your Function Execution Units by 1,024,000 to get GBsec. Execution count requires no translation. Based on the current pricing you pay $0.20 per million executions.

Comment: Has this all changed now? I can't relate the advice given here to anything I'm seeing in the portal

Comment: @StevenElliott I can't relate it either. On the 'Platform features' tab there's an 'All settings' button on the general settings group, I at least managed to get the in- and out-going traffic from that.

Comment: I'm looking for the same but can't find it... does that mean this question is now 'unanswered'? ;o)

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer to your question is "yes".

Use the Azure Monitor Metrics REST API to get FunctionExecutionUnits and FunctionExecutionCount metrics.

This sample call:
`az monitor metrics list --resource /subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/pbconsumptionexample/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/pbconsumptionexample --metric FunctionExecutionUnits,FunctionExecutionCount --aggregation Total --interval PT1M`

yields the following sample output shows 153600 MB-milliseconds, or .15 GB-ms:

```json
"name": {
    "additionalProperties": {},
    "localizedValue": "Function Execution Units",
    "value": "FunctionExecutionUnits"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "pbconsumptionexample",
  "timeseries": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": {},
      "data": [
        {
          "additionalProperties": {},
          "average": null,
          "count": null,
          "maximum": null,
          "minimum": null,
          "timeStamp": "2018-04-13T23:40:00+00:00",
          "total": 153600.0
        }
      ],
      "metadatavalues": []
    }
  ],
```

Here's an explanation of how:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ#how-can-i-access-execution-count-and-gb-seconds-programmatically

For greater context:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ