# Understanding Azure Functions behavior

Tags: .net, multithreading, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to make a mental shift towards that serverless thing and I found myself not understanding how to port my existing back-end code. I need to clarify the following assumptions:

1. Is an Azure Function considered to be a single-threaded piece of code?
2. Is it always a bad idea to use TPL and PLINQ inside a function?
3. How much is overhead of `static` members compared to regular app service?
   Basically, do we have any guarantees on `AppDomain` life time?
4. If I use a logging framework such as **NLog** or **log4net** whose async appenders require a dedicated thread do I need to be worried of anything?
5. How can I monitor how much memory *each* function run took?
6. Is it possible to setup a DI container so that my dependencies are injected into `Run` method? Something like that:

   ```
   [FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
   public async Task RunAsync(
      [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "meconn")]
      string myQueueItem,
      IBusinessLogicService blService,
      ILogService logService,
      IMailingService mailService) {
   }
   ```
7. Is it possible to get a `CancellationToken` in `Run` method so that I can cancel/shutdown gracefully?

Answer (score 6):

1. It depends on what you mean by "single threaded piece of code". At a high level, you should view the code you write in your function similar to how you might write code in an ASP.NET MVC controller method. A single event occurred (such as a HTTP request), a particular machine running your application has received that event and your code describes how to handle it. The dynamic scale capabilities of Azure Functions will never take a single execution and transparently distribute that execution over multiple threads or machines. If you have a scenario where a large amount of work has to be done based on a single event then you should split your work up across multiple functions so that the system can scale it out. One of the easiest ways to do this is with queues.
2. There are many scenarios where using TPL is valid. For example, your function might pull data from 3 different data sources and combine it into one result. In this case it would make sense to initiate those 3 async operations in parallel. I'm not quite as sure in regards to PLINQ. What I would say is that when you have significant computations that need to happen in parallel for efficiency purposes, you are best off splitting those computations into separate function executions (e.g. using queues as I mentioned above).
3. You can use static variables with basically no overhead, but there is no guarantee around app domain lifetime. So you need to be prepared to reinitialize those variables whenever required.
4. Azure Functions does not currently expose per function memory usage stats. There is usage stats at the function app level, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399678/azure-functions-memory-consumption-unit-usage) for info.
5. Azure Functions does not currently have support for DI.
6. Yes, simply define your function as an async function that returns a Task and have it accept a cancellation token and one will be passed to you.