# How can I monitor the memory used by my Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I monitor the memory used by my Azure Functions?

The pricing calculator memory goes from 128 MB, up to the 1.5 GB. And the time has a 1 second *de minimus*

So is the minimum cost for each call the 128 MB x 1 second charge?

And how can I check what the memory & time footprint really are?

Answer (score -4):

Details of how this calculation is made is provided here: [Azure Functions Billing Calculations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/functions/)

Functions are billed based on observed resource consumption measured in **Gigabyte Seconds (GB-s)**

Also, there is a free grant of **4,00,000 GB-s** per month.

In order to understand the billing calculations, you will also need to know how many times your function gets called in a month and what is the duration of each execution.

[image: Azure Functions Pricing]

**EDIT:**

As Mikhail has suggested refer the following thread for monitoring Memory:
[Azure Functions memory / consumption unit usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399678/azure-functions-memory-consumption-unit-usage)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of how to monitor the memory usage

Comment: You have already answered it so I did not include it in my response. Feel free to add it my response.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't an answer ...