# Calculating Azure function compute usage per tenant

Tags: azure, azure-functions, multi-tenant

How do I find out compute usage of Azure function per tenant.

There is a similar question here - [Azure Functions memory / consumption unit usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399678/azure-functions-memory-consumption-unit-usage/41403722#41403722)

But it doesn't answer how this could be monitor per tenant when the resource is shared between multiple tenants.

Is it possible to set up custom telemetry, including tenant ID, on the function app, like so - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions

and segment the data according to tenant Id on application insights? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-metrics-explorer#segment-your-data

Comment: What is your definition of tenant? You can see your GB-sec bill by Function App. If your tenants are each using different Function Apps, you should be able to split it up that way.

Comment: It is a multi-tenant app with a database per tenant- Look at C. here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns

The tenants are not each using a different Function Apps. They all shared the same node? (Unless I've understood the model wrongly) Thanks

Comment: Ah, yes. If you have a Function App that multiple tenants are sharing, it would be more difficult to do. You will mostly be forced to estimate it using App Insights duration metrics. We don't offer per execution GB-sec metrics today.